# Why in jquery all of the text field can connect to the Javascript file BUT only one is left out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why in jquery all of the text field can connect to the Javascript file BUT only one is left out when I insert linking It won't work!

What works is I insert it in HTML and it works fine the validate:

```
<tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" id="price" name="Price" class='form-control' style="required: true; number: true" maxlength="6"/> 
            </td>
            <script>
            $("#price").on("keyup", function(){
            var valid = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
            val = this.value;

           if(!valid){
           console.log("Invalid input!");
           this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
        }
        });
            </script>
        </tr>
```

But When I insert just this it won't work:

```
<tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" id="price" name="Price" class='form-control' style="required: true; number: true" maxlength="6"/> 
            </td>
            <script src="js/script.js">
            </script>
        </tr>
```

**This is my full code in HTML the jquery file its just link to another folder.
This is my previous code that works in the browser the validation works but when I insert linking script it doesn't work :-**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create New Promotions</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desaru.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css" type="text/css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Scripts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>   


    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->


<script>
$(document).ready(function() { // website fully loaded
    $('#submit').click(function() { //if button id=submit click trigger function down
        var name = $('#foldername').val(); //retrieve input for folder name
        var httpvar = 'http://211.25.118.147';
        var defaultfolder = '/resource/';
        //alert(name); get retrieve test name 

        if(name==""){ // if foldername input blank
            alert("Insert folder name");
            }

        else {
            $.ajax( {
            url : "addfolder.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {foldername : name}, //pass input foldername = name(variable declare at the top) foldername name base on html that set
            success: function(result){ //if success will sent the post data
                //alert(result);

                if (result=="success") { //based on output echo addfolder.php

                    alert("File "+name+" has been added");

                    $("#SelectImageFolder option[value='.."+defaultfolder+name+"']").remove();

                    $("#SelectImageFolder").append($('<option>', { //add new options
                        value : ".."+defaultfolder+name ,
                        text : httpvar+defaultfolder+name
                        }))

                    $("#SelectImageFolder option:last").attr("selected", "selected");//auto select the last option

                    }

                else if(result=="fail") {// if the file exist then result will fail to create the file
                    alert("Something wrong happened");
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        }
        })
    });


</script>


    <br/>
    <?php
    include('header.html');  ?>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div id="scrollbox">
    <!-- Content Section -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1><strong>Create New Promotions</strong></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <br/> 


<form action="PromotionsProcess.php"  name="Form" onsubmit="return validateform()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
        <!--<tr>
            <td>Class</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type='text' name='Class' readonly class='form-control' maxlength="20" value='Promotions'/>
            </td>
        </tr>-->
        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Category...  </option>
               <option value="F&B"> F&B  </option>
               <option value="Hotel"> Hotel  </option>
               <option value="Merchant"> Merchant  </option>
             </select>
             </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Item...  </option>
               <option value="Coffee"> Coffee  </option>
               <option value="Spa"> Spa  </option>
               <option value="Icecream"> Icecream  </option>
               <option value="Sungear"> Sungear  </option>
               <option value="Burger"> Burger  </option>
               <option value="Buffet"> Buffet  </option>
             </select>
             </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input required type='text' name='Title' class='form-control' maxlength="50"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Details Header</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input required type='text' name="DetailsHeader" class='form-control' maxlength="50"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Details</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <textarea required name="Details" rows="8" id="Details" class='form-control' maxlength="255"/></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" id="price" name="Price" class='form-control' style="required: true; number: true" maxlength="6"/> 
            </td>
            <script>
            $("#price").on("keyup", function(){
            var valid = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
            val = this.value;

           if(!valid){
           console.log("Invalid input!");
           this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
        }
});
            </script>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Promo Validity</td>
            <td colspan="2"> 
                <input type="text" name="PromoValidity" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Promo Grouping</td>
            <td colspan="2"> 
                <input type="text" name="PromoGrouping" class='form-control' maxlength="20"/>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Promo Text</td>
            <td colspan="2"> 
                <input type="text" name="PromoText" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Promo Code</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="PromoCode" name="PromoCode" class='form-control' style="text-transform: uppercase" maxlength="100"/><br/>
                <!--<input type="text" name="Ecc" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/><br/>
                <input type="text" name="Size" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Promo Images</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="file" id="FilePromoImage" name="FilePromoImage" maxlength="300"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Image Folder</td>
            <td colspan="2"> 
               <select name="SelectImageFolder" id="SelectImageFolder" class='form-control'>
                                  <option value="selected" selected="selected">Select a folder</option>
                                  <?php
                                        $dirs = glob("../resource/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

                                        // create variable constant url
                                        $httpvar = 'http://211.25.118.147';

                                        foreach($dirs as $val){
                                            $httpcon = str_replace("..",$httpvar,$val);
                                            echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$httpcon."</option>\n";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                </select><br/>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="foldername" id="foldername" placeholder="Folder Name" class='form-control' maxlength="100" />
                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button  type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn"/>Add Folder</button>
                 </span>
              </div></td>
              <script src="js/script.js"></script>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>List Images</td>
             <td colspan="2">
                 <input type="file" name="FileListImage" id="FileListImage">
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Carousel 1</td>
             <td colspan="2">
                 <input required type="file" name="FileCarousel1" id="FileCarousel1">
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Carousel 2</td>
             <td colspan="2">
                 <input type="file" name="FileCarousel2" id="FileCarousel2">
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Carousel 3</td>
             <td colspan="2">
                 <input type="file" name="FileCarousel3" id="FileCarousel3">
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Carousel 4</td>
             <td colspan="2">
                 <input type="file" name="FileCarousel4" id="FileCarousel4">
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Carousel 5</td>
             <td colspan="2">
                 <input type="file" name="FileCarousel5" id="FileCarousel5">
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Carousel 6</td>
             <td colspan="2">
                 <input type="file" name="FileCarousel6" id="FileCarousel6">
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Button Promo</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                 <input type="text" name="ButtonPromo" class='form-control' maxlength="20"/>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>More Details</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="MoreDetails" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Valid From</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" required id="ValidFrom" readonly name="ValidFrom" class='form-control' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Valid To</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" required id="ValidTo" readonly name="ValidTo" class='form-control' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Status...  </option>
               <option value="Active"> Active  </option>
               <option value="Inactive"> Inactive  </option>
             </select>
             </div>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr>
            <td>QR Code</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="QRCode" class='form-control' maxlength="300"/>
            </td>
        </tr>-->
        <tr>
            <td></td>
          <td colspan="2">
                <input type='submit' name='Add' value='Save' class='btn btn-warning' />
                <a href='Promotions.php' class='btn btn-danger'>Back</a>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</form>
</div>
    <!-- End Content Section -->
    <?php
    include('footer.html');  ?>
    </div>

<script src="js/script.js">
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Place your script code in  `$(function(){ ... }`. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377609/js-code-is-not-working-in-an-external-file-but-works-file-when-placed-in-the-sa

Comment: It still can't work...

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail. It's not at all clear what *"one is left out"* means

Comment: I try the function and some example in the link its still the same it can't work through like linking to the js file

Comment: Any errors in browser developer tools console? Did you include jQuery.js script?

Comment: Most of my text field like phone number validation and code text field validation seems to work but when it comes to price validation it can't seems to work on price validation text field

Comment: yes i did insert the linking script ady...

Comment: Is the script attached? Do you see script added in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Is the code in your “script.js” file wrapped inside the jQuery function?

```
$(function(){
// your code here.

$("#price").on("keyup", function(){
            var valid = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
            val = this.value;

           if(!valid){
           console.log("Invalid input!");
           this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
        }
});
```

Also in your file structure be sure the you have you index.html (or whatever you called you html file and then your “JS” folder which has your “script.js” file. This is based on the script path that you used. (js/script.js)

It might be best to take all of your custom JS code, put it in your script.js file and just link it at the bottom of the page. I think part of the problem is that you are referencing DOM elements that may not have loaded in the page yet. The reference to the submit button for example does not look like it should work based on where it is.

A thing to keep in mind or to get to know really well is the browser [critical rendering path](https://medium.com/@luisvieira_gmr/understanding-the-critical-rendering-path-rendering-pages-in-1-second-735c6e45b47a). The code that you have is going to render the HTML, then the CSS, then the script tags in the order in which they are placed. I will load your jQuery fine but the JS code that references the “submit” but should work because the button has not been rendered on the page yet.

That’s just what I noted. My best guess is to place all your custom code in the JS file and place it at the bottom of the page. It should work then.

Here are a couple of good videos on the critical rendering path also.

[critical rendering path 1](https://youtu.be/PkOBnYxqj3k)
[critical rendering path 2](https://youtu.be/YV1nKLWoARQ)

Comment: Is jQuery loaded? Do you have a script tag linking jQuery in the header of the page?

Comment: If you are using the Chrome browser to develop; as if there where any other; then you can hit f12, then go to sources. There you should see jQuery and the should be a folder which should have your script.js file. If you are linking things correctly.

Comment: Yes the script inside the head and body tag